# Can anyone explain my problem in tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                            [1,1,1],
                            [1,0,1],
                            [0,1,1]])

training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]])

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")
    ])

model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop",
              loss = "binary_crossentropy",
              metrics = ["accuracy"])

model.fit(training_inputs,training_outputs,epochs=1)

prediction = model.predict(np.array([[1,1,0]]))
```

print(prediction)

it has these problems

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Αλέξης/Desktop/Youtube/test.py", line 21, in 
>       model.fit(training_inputs,training_outputs,epochs=1)   File "C:\Users\Αλέξης\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 709, in fit
>       shuffle=shuffle)   File "C:\Users\Αλέξης\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2651, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')   File "C:\Users\Αλέξης\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py",
>   line 376, in standardize_input_data
>       'with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with
>   shape (4, 3)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Seems like the dimensions of your training input are not matching the ones given by the  input_shape

Answer (score 0):

I delete the square brackets for the training outputs array so that each entry in training inputs has an associated class instead of just the first one having 4

I also deleted the flatten layer and set the input_shape parameter to the dense layer

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                        [1,1,1],
                        [1,0,1],
                        [0,1,1]])

training_outputs = np.array([0,1,1,0])

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid",input_shape=(3,))
])

model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop",
          loss = "binary_crossentropy",
          metrics = ["accuracy"])

model.fit(training_inputs,training_outputs,epochs=1)
```

Comment: its invalid syntax like this (,3)

Comment: how about if you write just 3

Comment: i tried 3 it doesnt take it, but i used (3,) but it has these problems
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 4 input samples and 1 target samples.

Comment: how about now, i removed the Flatten layer, you dont really need it. Th reason you get this error is becuase your `training_outputs` isa 2d array instead of 1d

Answer (score 0):

If you check your arrays shapes, you will see the problem

```
print(training_inputs.shape)
print(training_outputs.shape)

Output:
(4, 3)
(4,)
```

Your model expects an input array of size (Batch size, 3), and that's ok. But your model outputs an array of size (Batch size, 1), thus your label array must to have the same size. You can easily fix that using ***np.expand_dims***.

Just turn

```
training_outputs = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
```

Into

```
training_outputs = np.expand_dims(
    np.array([0,1,1,0]),
    axis = 1
)
```